# How can I add a URL in Azure Devops using Power Automate?

Tags: azure-devops, power-automate

I have an automated flow in Power Automate that looks at a submitted MS form and then creates a feature, user story, and tasks underneath it in Azure Devops. Then, it sends an email saying that a new item was created. In the description of the feature in Devops, I need to add the URL of the attachment(s) that the person adds when they fill out the form. I tried adding the dynamic content of the attachment in the "create a work item" description box, but when it goes to Devops it's very long and I want it to be shorter.

I have tried using a hyperlink, but when I clicked on it in Devops it would create an error message saying that it was a dangerous request title.

Answer (score 0):

The link to the uploaded file (the answer to the Upload File question) should be nested within the answer of question. Use can use an expression to retrieve the answer, convert it to an array with a [json](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#json) function and retrieve the link value of the [first](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#first) item.

Below is an example in a Compose action.
*Make sure you update the r9479... question id by your specific question id.*

```
first(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r9479088045e84b20b8ebbbce9191d6e1']))['link']
```

[image]